# Problems with Cloudinary and NextJS

Tags: nextjs13

I have this problem in my console:
**results { error: { message: 'unknown api_key' } }**

It happens because I'm trying to get images from my Cloudinary account, I've verified my cloud name, api key, api secret. The problem happens in this part of my code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
const results = await fetch(`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/resources/image`, {
headers: {
Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY + ':' + process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET).toString('base64')}`
}
  }).then(r => r.json());
console.log('results', results);
return {
props: {
}
  }
}
```

This is my .env.local:

```
CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME=my_cloud_name

CLOUDINARY_API_KEY=my_apy_key

CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET=my_api_secret
```

If someone could help me please!!

Comment: Esto es [es.so]. Para preguntas en inglés: [so].